# ASP.NET Meta refresh Force Download

Tags: c#, asp.net, meta-tags, force-download

I am using a meta refresh tag to point to a file that i want to download from a server. How do i make it so that it downloads all files, rather than opens them in the browser. I am adding the meta tag in code behind like this:

```
String filename = filenode.Element("name").Value.ToString();
HtmlMeta redirectMetaTag = new HtmlMeta();
redirectMetaTag.HttpEquiv = "Refresh";
redirectMetaTag.Content = string.Format("2;url=http://example.example.net/example/" + filename);
this.Header.Controls.Add(redirectMetaTag);
```

At the moment, thie file eg a jpg is just being opened in the browser

Comment: And...what is hapenning?

Comment: Just to clarify, do you want to the browser open a **Save As** dialog in place of displaying the image?

Comment: yes thats what i would like, and it is what it does for some types eg zip files

Answer (score 0):

If you want to force the browser to open a **Save As** dialog you must add a couple of custom headers for the page.

I sugggest you to use the TransmitFile function:

```
Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment; filename=[your-file-name]");
Response.TransmitFile( Server.MapPath("~/images/[your-file-name]") );
Response.End();
```

It will automatically write the file content to the **OutputStream** of the **Response**.

Comment: as this download is happening directly after a response.redirect, i can't use the response.transmitfile method. Also this makes it harder to download all type of files. Any other suggestion?

Comment: You can, just create an ASP page that receives the file name in que querystring or session. Then you redirect to this ASP page passing the image that you want.

Comment: i tried endlessly to get the response.transmitfile method to work on the Page_Load event of the aspx page. What you said is what i tried, until going to the meta refresh tag.

Comment: Did you replace the file name brackets with your current file name? It is working, I did make a test project for it.

Comment: how are you navigating from the firsdt page to this page with the transmit file on page_load?